# "The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time" while installing a Nuxt3 app

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I try to creat new nuxt app using fallowing command

```
npx nuxi init my-app
```

successfully creating new app with Nuxt 3.0 stable inside but i get this annoying response

```
Nuxi 3.0.0-rc.10                                                                                              15:04:22

 ERROR  (node:35527) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

What confuses me is the version of **Nuxi 3.0.0-rc.10** and the Error I belive it comes from node.

node - 18.12.1

npm - 8.19.2

git - 2.38.1

Answer (score 22):

It was enough for me to upgrade to node `18.13.0`

Comment: I'm deploying to Vercel, which only seems to support up to 18.12.1 currently. I'm not sure what you mean by "You can also try `--no-experimental-fetch` flag." It seems like it would do the opposite of what I want. https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/#fetch-experimental

Comment: +1 what Ryan said "It's possible to disable the API by supplying the --no-experimental-fetch command-line flag." - that would stop you fetch()ing, rather than disable the warning.

Comment: Vercel should provide minor and patch versions. At least that's what they claim in docs. You can read more here https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions/runtimes/node-js#node.js-version

You could try adding this to `package.json`:
`{"engines": { "node":  ">=18.13.0" }}`

Comment: Now node 20 is out and about to enter LTS next month  This definitely helped remove the error though 

Answer (score 3):

First off, you should be running `Nuxt 3.0.0` (stable version), not the RC.

Also, this is a warning hence something that you can omit. Especially because it is tied to Node v18 itself and not Vue/Nuxt. Some details on how to suppress the warning are available here: https://github.com/netlify/cli/issues/4608#issuecomment-1223696635

As for the warning, it is a common thing to have experimental features marked until they are fully stable. Here is the [official source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V18.md#fetch-experimental) for that one.

Comment: How to run Nuxt 3.0.0 ( stable version ) and not RC ?
I just open a terminal and run the command after that I get the response.
Do I need to upgrade Nuxi ?
I did this from other PC and do not get the warning and Nuxi was 3.0.0

Comment: @martcube not sure why `nuxi` is not fetching the latest version in your case. If you have it installed, please give it an upgrade. Otherwise, if you don't have it installed and are fetching it remotely (with `npx`), it should be good. Otherwise, you can also manually set `"nuxt": "3.0.0"` in your `package.json > devDependencies`. Still, the issue is not related to Nuxt as explained.

Comment: even tho is showing to me that is running Nuxi-rc-10 it still installs Nuxt3.0.0.
That  is strange to me. Maybe I have some wrong configuration in my PC I just cant trace it.

Comment: Now sure where you can see that it installs 3.0.0, but the info displayed when you launch your dev server is still the one to believe. Again, unrelated to the warning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on an app using next.js and I'm also getting this error:

```
ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
```

I was using node version 18.0.0

Switching to node version 19.8.1 fixed it for me.

Comment: You should avoid odd versions of Node since they will never be LTS https://nodejs.dev/en/about/releases/ mode can be found here. At this time though the latest version on 18 does not have this message and 20 is available and about to enter LTS next month.

Answer (score -1):

I helped upgrade the version node
`v18.12.1 -> v19.4.0`

Comment: I don't recommend using a non LTS version.

Comment: You should avoid odd versions of Node since they will never be LTS nodejs.dev/en/about/releases mode can be found here. At this time though the latest version on 18 does not have this message and 20 is available and about to enter LTS next month.